# DbContext as Dependency injection in the controllers constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I am working on a asp.net mvc project. And I wonder if the setup of the project is correct. So just some advice

Because I see this:

```cs
public IndicatorController(
    IndicatorService indicatorService,
    PatientLogService patientLogService,
    PatientDbContext dbContext,
    AppIdentityDbContext identityDbContext,
    MedicalDbContext medicalDbContext,
    IMeasurementProcessor measurementProcessor,
    IMeasurementRepository measurementRepository,
    IEntryRepository entryRepository,
    IPersonalFieldBoundaryRepository personalFieldBoundaryRepository,
    IEmailSender emailSender,
    IndicatorActionService indicatorActionService,
    IndicatorBuilderContext indicatorBuilderContext,
    IPatientIndicatorService patientIndicatorService,
    ViewRender viewRender,
    IEmailSender messageSender,
    IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    : base(dbContext, identityDbContext, medicalDbContext, loggerFactory)
{
    _patientLogService = patientLogService;
    _indicatorService = indicatorService;
    _measurementProcessor = measurementProcessor;
    _measurementRepository = measurementRepository;
    _entryRepository = entryRepository;
    _personalFieldBoundaryRepository = personalFieldBoundaryRepository;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _indicatorActionService = indicatorActionService;
    _indicatorBuilderContext = indicatorBuilderContext;
    _patientIndicatorService = patientIndicatorService;
    _viewRender = viewRender;
    _messageSender = messageSender;
    _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
}
```

And the base Controller looks like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected PatientDbContext _patientDbContext;
    protected MedicalDbContext _medicalDbContext;
    protected readonly AppIdentityDbContext _identityDbContext;

    protected readonly ILogger _logger;

    public string CurrentUserId => User.FindFirstValue(JwtClaimTypes.Subject);

    private Task<Participant> _participant;
    private Task<UserIdentity> _userIdentity;

    public Task<Participant> Participant => _participant ?? (_participant = LoadParticipant());

    public Task<UserIdentity> UserIdentity => _userIdentity ?? (_userIdentity = LoadUserIdentity());

    public BaseController(
        PatientDbContext patientDbContext,
        AppIdentityDbContext identityDbContext,
        MedicalDbContext medicalDbContext,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _patientDbContext = patientDbContext;
        _medicalDbContext = medicalDbContext;
        _identityDbContext = identityDbContext;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BaseController>();
    }

    private async Task<Participant> LoadParticipant()
    {
        return !RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("participantId")
            || !Guid.TryParse(RouteData.Values["participantId"].ToString(), out Guid participantId)
            ? null : await _patientDbContext.Participants.FindAsync(participantId);
    }

    private async Task<UserIdentity> LoadUserIdentity()
    {
        var participant = await Participant;
        return await _identityDbContext.Users
            .Include(i => i.ParticipantIdentity)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == participant.UserIdentityId);
    }
}
```

But so my question is: Is this the correct way to inject the   PatientDbContext dbContext directly into the controllers constructor?

Thank you

But for example the AdviseService , there you directly inject the dbcontext:

```cs
public class AdviceService
{
    private static readonly HtmlSanitizer s_htmlSanitizer = HtmlSanitizerProvider.GetSanitizer();

    private readonly PatientDbContext _patientDbContext;
    private readonly MedicalDbContext _medicalDbContext;
    private readonly AppIdentityDbContext _identityDbContext;
    private readonly AdviceLayoutFactory _adviceLayoutFactory;
    private readonly PatientLogService _patientLogService;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializerSettings;
    private readonly ChatDbContext _chatDbContext;

    public AdviceService(
        PatientDbContext patientDbContext,
        MedicalDbContext medicalDbContext,
        ChatDbContext chatDbContext,
        AppIdentityDbContext identityDbContext,
        AdviceLayoutFactory adviceLayoutFactory,
        PatientLogService patientLogService,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings)
    {
        _patientDbContext = patientDbContext;
        _medicalDbContext = medicalDbContext;
        _identityDbContext = identityDbContext;
        _adviceLayoutFactory = adviceLayoutFactory;
        _patientLogService = patientLogService;
        _jsonSerializerSettings = jsonSerializerSettings;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AdviceService>();
        _chatDbContext = chatDbContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I have lots of things to say about this code! Sooo many injected parameters strongly suggests your objects are doing way too much ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). Next, I don't understand why you are injecting both services and contexts into the contoller. Keep the context away form the controller and inject them directly into the services.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reply! I already thought there was someting wrong about it. But you made a lot of things clear. Thank you

Comment: It's not incorrect per see to inject runtime data objects such as DbContext into your components. This means you are practicing the [Closure Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/ccm). Another model is to load runtime data objects from ambient storage; that model is called the [Ambient Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/acm).

Comment: Considering the size of your controller, however, I expect it to violate the Single Responsibility Principle and would likely benefit from extracting dependencies and their behavior out of the controller using the [Facade Services refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

Comment: Thank you all. But can you maybe make a sample class how to seperate those things. THank you

Comment: @DavidG. I updated the post

Comment: btw, this is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh, I didnt knew that. Almost for everything is a apart forum